# Disabling textbox in gridview using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Part of my gridview looks like this:

```
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mortality Rate" SortExpression="Other2">
                <EditItemTemplate >
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAppLimit" Text='<%#Bind("Other2")%>' runat="server" width="60px" maxlength="14">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RangeValidator ID="RVAppLimit" Type="Currency" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAppLimit"  
                            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="" Font-Size="8pt" 
                            CssClass="msgerror" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="200" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender" ValidationGroup="group1"> 
                    </asp:RangeValidator>  
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAppLimit" Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Other2") %>' >
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm trying to get the asp TextBox ID and asp Label ID in this way when I click on a asp LinkButton:

```
        var $arrL = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('span[id$="lblAppLimit"]');
        var $lbl = $arrL[0];
        ($lbl).disabled = true;
        alert (($lbl).disabled);

        var $arrT = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtAppLimit"]').val();
        var $txt = $arrT[0];
        alert (($txt).innerHTML);
```

I have no problem disabling lblAppLimit, however I'm not able to get the textbox ID to disable it. What is wrong with my code above?

Just to add on another note, when I click on view source on my browser, I'm able to see lblAppLimit, but not txtAppLimit.

Comment: Probably you are not in edit mode , that's why...

Comment: @Legends What do you mean?

Comment: `txtAppLimit` is in `EditItemTemplate` so it will only work if the grid is in edit mode

Comment: too little code to help you, show us the complete grid markup and your serverside grid handling code.

Comment: @Ansari it's not working even when I'm in edit mode.

Comment: @AaronTan check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txtAppLimit` is in `EditItemTemplate` so it will only work if the grid is in edit mode

So in edit mode try this script

```
var $arrT = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id*="txtAppLimit"]').val();
        var $txt = $arrT[0];
        alert (($txt).innerHTML);
```

i don't know why you are using `$arrT[0]` but this will surely work in edit mode

```
$('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id*="txtAppLimit"]').val()
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make you txtAppLimit as STATIC like this :

1 `<asp:TextBox ID="txtAppLimit" Text='<%#Bind("Other2")%>' width="60px" maxlength="14" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

and change the jquery to :

1 `$(this).find('input:text[id="txtAppLimit"]').val();`

**Update:**
You can also try with adding class to every TextBoxes like txtclass1,txtclass2

```
alert($(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find(".txtclass1").val()); 
alert($(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find(".txtclass2").val());
```

Comment: I'm on .NET Framework 2.0, I can't get ClientIDMode to work in my application. Do you have any other suggestions?